# How to import data in Microsoft Access from csv file?

Tags: ms-access

I am currently using the [routine proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568310/vba-transfertext-specificationname/5569640#5569640) by [Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185412/vivek) to export the data of an Access 2013 table (tables linked by dsn odbc) to a csv file
Everything works fine

But how to do the reverse operation, therefore having the table empty and wanting to import (via vba code then automatically) the same data exported before, how to proceed?

Comment: Do you want to do it via code for automation, or do it manually? Solution to do manually: https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/how-to-import-csv-into-microsoft-access-database/

Comment: Not manually, automatically via vba code  

What I would like to create are two generic functions that were able to export and import data from any table in the database, regardless of the structure of the tables

Obviously the data import will be performed exclusively from the csv files that have been written with the data export function from that table

Comment: Better add that info to the question for clarification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA procedure to import csv file into access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275356/vba-procedure-to-import-csv-file-into-access)

Comment: A quick search with the keywords give me multiple results. Next time try to search first before posting a question 
keywords import csv into access database vba

Comment: "... give me multiple results...."  NO
For exporting and importing data on Microsoft Access table the DoCmd.Transfertext command is mainly used
But, TransferText require a table structure
The example of Vivek is based on a different approch
His example not require table structure, but is function correctly
Then my question is, how to 'invert' the example to import data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read/Parse text file line by line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

But why use this severely limited file format? Export to an Access database, and you keep everything from the original table:

```vb
DbEngine(0).CreateDatabase "C:\Test\Backup.accdb", dbLangGeneral, dbVersion120
DoCmd.CopyObject "C:\Test\Backup.accdb", "Products", acTable, "Products"
```

If you wish to copy *all* tables in the database, use this simple call:

```vb
SaveAsText 6, "", "C:\Test\Tables.accdb"
```